# xargs issue with grepped files containing spaces

Tags: linux, bash, grep, find, xargs

I have a range of .html files all containing spaces in between.

What I need is to locate the file using find in conjunction with grep, and if a match is found, basically I just want xargs to open it in view mode using less. Nothing fancy.

This is what I tried

```
pietro@scum:~/Downloads$ find |grep 'Register\sfor\srehousing.html' |xargs -trE  less
echo ./Register for rehousing.html 
./Register for rehousing.html

pietro@scum:~/Downloads$ find |grep 'Register\sfor\srehousing.html' |xargs -0 less
./Register for rehousing.html
: No such file or directory
```

I have gone through the xargs man but I just can't figure out why xargs doesn't pickup the filename + PATH to file and execute the less command.

The file does exist and here is how it looks

```
pietro@scum:~/Downloads$ ls -l |grep 'Register\sfor\srehousing.html' 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pietro pietro    764611 Mar 14 14:44 Register for rehousing.html
```

Comment: Why don't you use `find -name` instead of `find | grep` ?

Comment: @RoVo Simply I do not know how to use find -name when file contains spaces in between.

Comment: and why don't you use `less "Register for rehousing.html"` if you know the file exists?

Comment: In reality this will be one of the few functions I am adding to an interactive script I am creating. I just needed to figure out how it would work before embedding it to the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
xargs -d '\n' less
```

the input to xargs, in your case are not null character terminated

Comment: Wow that worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a pipe, use `find` only with `-name` instead of `grep` and `-exec` instead of `xargs`:

```
find . -name 'Register for rehousing.html' -exec less {} \;
```